# Setting Marker Properties using Scripts

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology, style

Re-posting the question with updates.
I have a following piece of code that is allowing me to change the symbol properties.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
iter = layer.getFeatures()
layer.rendererV2().symbol().symbolLayer(0).setName('triangle')
layer.rendererV2().symbol().setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,255,255))
layer.triggerRepaint
```

How do i get the following expression incorporated into the python script

```
u'size_dd_expression': u'CASE WHEN  "BCCH"  < 200 THEN 25\r\nWHEN "BCCH">     200 THEN 12 \r\nEND'
```

OR

```
u'color_dd_expression':u'CASE WHEN  "STATUS"  = \'ON\' THEN  color_rgba(0,255,0,255)\r\n  WHEN  "STATUS"  = \'OFF\' THEN  color_rgba(255,0,0,100)\r\nEND'
```

OR

```
 u'angle_dd_expression': u'"AZIMUTH" +180'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `createSymbolLayer()` class when creating a new symbol and define the properties with the rules you specified:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
registry = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance()
symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())

# Create new SimpleMarker style
triangle = registry.symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleMarker").createSymbolLayer(
    {'name': 'triangle', 
     u'color_dd_expression':u'CASE WHEN "STATUS" = \'ON\' THEN  color_rgba(0,255,0,255)\r\nWHEN "STATUS" = \'OFF\' THEN  color_rgba(255,0,0,100)\r\nEND', 
     'color_border': '0,0,0', 
     'offset': '0,0', 
     u'size_dd_expression': u'CASE WHEN "BCCH" < 200 THEN 25\r\nWHEN "BCCH" > 200 THEN 12 \r\nEND', 
     u'angle_dd_expression': u'"AZIMUTH" +180'})

# Delete previous symbol style
symbol.deleteSymbolLayer(0)
symbol.appendSymbolLayer(triangle)

# Update renderer of current layer
renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(symbol)
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Result:

[image: Result]

---

*Tested on QGIS 2.16.1-Nødebo.*

Comment: @Arindam - Most welcome! Glad it worked :)